# React Native: where to place Navigators for other screens?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My Application has a `BottomTabNavigator`, each Tab is linked to a component, which is a `StackNavigator`.
With that implementation, I can easily switch between the tab screens and also see a detailed screen.

Here is the code of my Screen component:

```
export default function Screen ({props, children}) {
    
    return (
        <>
        <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                cardShadowEnabled: false,
                header: (props) => {
                    return <Header {...props} />
                },
            }}
        >
            <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
            <View style={styles.container}>{ children }</View>
        </SafeAreaView>
        <TabNavigator i18n={i18n}/>
        </>
    );
}
```

In the header component, I have an Icon, which onPress needs to navigate to the SettingsScreen.

I am afraid that I am not sure if this is the right implementation of the SettingsNavigator and if yes, how is possible on click on my header menu to navigate to the SettingsScreen.

Here is my Header.js code:

```
export default function Header (props, navigation) {
    ...
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.link} onPress={navigation.navigate("Settings")}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="tune" size={32} />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
};
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: navigation.navigate is not a function.(In
> 'navigation.navigate("Settings")', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)

How can I access the navigation from my Header component?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a correct implementation.

Please try like following

```
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName={Routes.SignIn}
  screenOptions={{
    cardShadowEnabled: false,

    header: (props) => {
      return <Header {...props} />
    },
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen name={Routes.SignIn} component={SignInScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name={Routes.ForgotPassword} component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name={Routes.SignUp} component={SignUpScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: I have changed the implementation, but now I am receiving the following error: Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with NavigationContainer. This is maybe because of the TabNavigator. But how to have both on each Screen?